# Calculations for one-sided confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value

I need help with understanding the result of µ*. Can someone show me the way to come to this result?
Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $p=P_{\mu=0}(Z>\sqrt{n}\bar{x})$, we have $Z_{1-p}=\sqrt{n}\bar{x}$, Thus $\bar{x}=Z_{1-p}/\sqrt{n}$. Finally, substituting this into the expression of $\mu_*=\bar{x}-Z_{1-\alpha}/\sqrt{n}$ yields $\mu_*=(Z_{1-p}-Z_{1-\alpha})/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: How do you come to $Z_{1-p}$?

Comment: From the definition of $1-p$ quantile of the standard normal distribution. For a random variable $Z$ of standard normal distribution, the definition of $z_{1-p}$ is $P(Z > z_{1-p}) = p$.